# Best way to notify user about application access?

Tags: authentication, coldfusion, user-accounts

I have application where administrators have to create accounts for the new users. Basically there is no option for random user to create account and access this app. The admin would have to enter some basic info like First, Last name, Email address, User name and then comes to the password. I have algorithm that generates unique passwords. I'm looking for the better option to handle this situation.

The old application worked this way: admin enters info, generates password and there is an option either to automatically notify users via email or admin will contact directly that user and provide login info. This method seems very inefficient and insecure at the same time. Sending info like user name and password in the email is definitely not recommended nowadays. I was wondering what would be a good approach?

Should I generate unique link with expiration date where user can enter the password? Or there is better way to handle this situation? I use JavaScript, JQuery and ColdFusion 2016 for this project.

Comment: You could auto-generate their first password, and then the invite process could initiate a reset password operation, which would generate a reset password link. Send them the reset password link in their invite.

Comment: @Redtopia maybe I didn't understand your answer but I wouldn't like to share user name and password through the email. I was thinking about email that would contain temporary link. When they click on the link they would need to enter the new password. I'm not sure if this is the best option.

Comment: All modern authentication systems are build on the presumption that you cannot securely share a password, even if it's encrypted. So, if you want to bring your authentication system up to modern standards, you would have to implement a reset password feature, which basically sets a token in your user record and expires. There are lots of articles that discuss how modern auth systems work, so you would have to figure that part out. My thought was that a reset password link would give the user the opportunity to set their own password, and could be integrated into your invite system somehow.

Comment: @Redtopia yes, I have already algoritham that generates token and sets expire timestamp. This is used if user requests password recovery. However, this same logic I would use for the invite process. I guess username would have to be included in that email, then user can type in their own new password. Does that make sense?

Comment: Since your admins are creating your new users anyway, I wouldn't see a problem with them generating a temporary, unique password that expires within 24 hours and must be reset on first use, and is sent in a seperate email or SMS message than the username. And possibly limit the functionality of the user until they can further validate who they are. Sending them the login link with the token would work, but it's really not a whole lot different for initial login than sending them a password to login. Just make the expiration short and require change after initial use.

Comment: @Shawn I had that before and sending password in the email is not recommended now days. Also taking route with link & token that has expiration time stamp saves the extra step of user having to change the password again. My solution for this situation would be to send them an email with username and link. They click on the link and create their password. Then they would need to login with that password and username. No need to reset the password in this case. I might be missing something but that seems less work for users.

Comment: @espresso_coffee For initial login, you aren't really sending them their password, but just a one-time, short-term method for initially accessing their account. It's not a whole lot different than the login token. With that, you're essentially sending them their access credential in a link. The reason you don't send a normal password through email is that it's easy to compromise. You can compromise the token link just as easily if you have access to their email. And for an actual password, nobody should know it except the user. But I do think that the token login is the most user-friendly.